# Field-level ACL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, acl, access-control, role-base-authorization

I have search SO, googled every combination of ACL, CodeIgniter, Role-based, etc and have found many good offerings for controlling access to controllers and methods, but have come up empty for something that give field-level control.

I downloaded a couple (phpgacl and zend acl) to see if they could be easily modified to suit my needs for field-level permissions.  So before I spend the time to create one from scratch...

**Question:** Is there a library and/or best practice to allow **field-level** restrictions based on a user's login?

Specifically I'm looking to, depending on the AD group membership of the user, have form fields either:

- Not appear
- Appear but be read-only
- Be editable

BTW, the AD group memberships are already available in a session variable, so I don't need that bit necessarily.  I've tagged this as both ACL and role-based, not to start another discussion on the differences, but because I'm willing to go either way if the package meets my needs.

Comment: I see a couple of votes to close.  Could you please let me know why the "not constructive" votes and how I could correct?  I checked the "How to Ask" and I did my homework, tried to be specific, I think it would be relavent to others (I can't be the only one looking for this, can I?), and I specifically tried to preempt "debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."  Please let me know what I can do to make this question better.

Comment: I have not, as of yet, come across any publicly available CI libraries that offer field-level ACL. You might have to use a combination of ACL and extension of the built-in form validation library to achieve what you need.

Comment: @Brendan Thanks for confirming.  That's where I'm headed next if nobody else has something.  Just didn't see anything in the body of knowledge.  If I do end up creating something, I'll post it for use.

Comment: @Brendan So, did you end up building anything that you can share?

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr I switched over to Laravel a couple years ago. Suggest you do the same. Eloquent > CI models.

Comment: @Brendan Thanks, but I'm already on CakePHP, just had this one old project done on CI... I can't spend time migrating it to something more robust and sensible like Cake or Laravel..Thanks anyways! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well I to answer one of your questions I am currently using a "flag based" ACL if you will. In my users table I have 3 fields, called Activated, Staffmember, Admin. I run 3 queries in 2 different models to check if the login credentials that were given

```
WHERE staffmember = 1
WHERE Admin = 1
WHERE activated = 1
```

if a record is returned I then turn that into a return value.

This is my if else statements to decide who sees what :

```
    function index()
{
    $this->load->model('staff_model'); // loads model that queries if username is associated with a admin or staff account
    if($staffmember = $this->staff_model->staffmember()) //Checks for staff value == 1 
    {
        if($is_admin = $this->staff_model->is_admin()) // Checks for admin value == 1
        {
            redirect('admin_controller/index'); // redirects to what the admin will see (the admin pages, add users, delete users, deactivate users, this way I set up a sorta CMS type system
        }else{ // If not admin == 1 meaning it can be a staff member == 1 
            $data['main_content'] = 'staff_homepage_view'; //sets up template for staff member
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data); // this will then load the view for staff member
        }
    }else{ // If not staff == 1 // then if it is not staff member it will load the view for a no permission account in this case : student 
        $data1['main_content'] = 'student_homepage_view';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data1); 
        }
    }
```

If you need to see model let me know. but this way I was able to set up what users can see via their account flag in the database.

This way as well, the admin, MUST BE a staff member, and this way the activated no permission account can not be a staffmember or admin.

So then what you can do is then set up in your users table a field called Edit

and in the controller then you can specify if Edit = 1 then user has full access to what is needed to be done, else can only be read. Now I don't know what you have to edit so I am kinda limited with the info I can supply you.